Etymology of 甘え
I'm making an assumption that because it's the same kanji and kunyomi, 甘え is the same historical base as 甘い 'sweet', and so the meaning, etymologically, is literally something like 'be sweet on someone'. What would the え ending be in this case? Or is this just a coincidence and 甘え and 甘い are in fact not from the same root?

Do you know the verb 甘える?

I don't know the etymology, but it can be understood as being sweet on/kind to oneself.

Dating
The noun 甘【あま】え appears relatively late in 1942, if the Nihon Kokugo Daijiten ("NKD") entry over here at Kotobank is to be trusted.
That said, this is simply the noun use of the 連用形【れんようけい】 or continuative / gerundive / masu-stem form of the verb 甘【あま】える.  This in turn is the modern form of classical verb 甘【あま】ゆ, which had the 下二段活用【しもにだんかつよう】, or "lower bigrade conjugation": "lower" in that most stem forms ended in /e/ (instead of "upper" /i/), and "bigrade" in that there were two vowel endings depending on the conjugation: the 終止形【しゅうしけい】 or terminal / conclusive / predicative form ended in /u/ (amayu), while other conjugation stems ended in /e/ (amae).  The modern verb 甘【あま】える is classed as 下一段活用【しもいちだんかつよう】 or "lower monograde conjugation", where "monograde" refers to the stems all ending in /e/ (no more amayu form).
If we look again at the corresponding NKD entry for the verb, we see a first citation in the 源氏物語【げんじものがたり】 or The Tale of Genji, treated by Japanese sources as having been authored over the years of roughly 1001–1014.
Derivation
The verb itself is from 甘【あま】, the stem of adjective 甘【あま】い ("sweet") + spontaneous / passive / potential verb-forming suffix -ゆ.  This is the same suffix we see in other verbs like classical 見【み】ゆ and 聞【き】こゆ, modern 見【み】える and 聞【き】こえる.
Sense Development

The original underlying meaning of 甘【あま】ゆ was something like "to be or become in a sweet state" (spontaneously / intransitively, action happening on its own).
This then expanded metaphorically to refer to "behaving in a sweet manner [in order to elicit some favorable response in someone else]".
Then by the late 1700s, we see senses more like "to take some kind of advantage of someone or take someone for granted, in assumption of a favorable response".

Those latter two senses are probably the main ones now, giving rise to English translations such as "to flatter, to fawn on, to behave sycophantically", and "to behave like a spoiled child".

Some source claims it comes from 甘いものを得る. I don’t know if it’s true though. But it makes sense.
